# how to crawl a page whose link is hidden until it is clicked

Tags: import.io

i want to get data of a page whose link needs to be clicked.

i have tried capturing the link field with a crawler and extractor with column validation set as link and html. but it doesnot return the actual link.
only after i click the link, a pop-up opens, from where i want the data.
each landing page has around 50 such links. i want to crawl each of these links.

i tried this with a connector but things get complex as there are around 90k queries. additionally the connector doesnot return the url of the page which would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting this data really depends on the website. Import is not able to extract data from popups. But, extracting the link path may be possible, depending on the structure of the website. If you are not able to extract the data with the tool, I would suggest using an xpath to obtain the link path.

To do this navigate to the page you want this data from, right click and select "inspect element." Select where the link path is on the page, right click again and select "select xpath." Go back to your Extractor and select the "advanced settings" icon and paste in your xpath. Again, this may not work, since it is dependant of how the website it structured, but still worth a try.

Thanks,
Meg

Comment: It should also be possible to use a connector